# Multiple files in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2017, phaser-framework

I am building a HTML5 game using Phaser. I am using Typescript for that. Now I want to make two classes. 'app.ts' is my main class. And it uses another class say 'Level.ts'. The code compiles, but when I run, I don't get the desired output. I am using import and export methods. Also, I am not able to debug it. I think it's because it doesn't know that 'app.ts' is the main script. Kindly suggest an easy way to link the two files.

I will also add the code:
LevelMap.ts

```
export class LevelMap
{
    constructor(game: Phaser.Game)
    {
        this.mGame = game;
    }

    mGame: Phaser.Game;

    public createLevel()
    {
        this.mGame.stage.backgroundColor = '#787878';
    }
}
```

And app.ts

```
import { LevelMap } from "./LevelMap";
class App
{   
    constructor()
    {
        this.game = new Phaser.Game(1920, 1080, Phaser.AUTO, 'content', { preload: this.preload, create: this.create, update: this.update });
    }

game: Phaser.Game;
map: Phaser.Tilemap;    

mLevelMap: LevelMap;

    preload()
    {
        this.mLevelMap = new LevelMap(this.game);
    }

    create()
    {
        this.mLevelMap.createLevel();       
    }

    update()
    {

    }

}

window.onload = () =>
{
    var game = new App();
};
```

The HTML File

```
<script src="Phaser/phaser.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
```

Comment: Did you include app.js in the HTML ? Or are you using a module system ?

Comment: Hello. I added the code. The background color doesn't change.